# How to create custom Icons in Ionic framework for fuel stations and food courts

Tags: icons, ionic-framework, application-icon

I need a requirement to have the food courts and fuel stations with google places API. I need to display in ionic (**tab.html**) as a separate modules for above two like fuel stations and food courts.

[image: Tabs for all modules]

Comment: Please have a look at this [Ionic blog](http://blog.ionic.io/building-ionicons/)   , also there is a discussion on [Ionic Forum](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/add-custom-icons/559/9). Please look into it if you have not seen it already.

Answer (score 0):

so if you want to make your icon font then you can use http://fontastic.me/, make your font icons, and then download them and include them in your project like you do ion icons. However if you just need a icon and it does not have to be a font icon (i.e. png, jpg) look at https://freeiconmaker.com/ I have used this site to make all of the icons for our enterprise app. It is intuitive easy to use and has tons of selections.